# JSON Stringify: Tabs in objects are converted to \t causing issue while upper casing the result

Tags: javascript, json

I have an Object,

```
var o = {
  "comments": "    notes" // it first 4 spaces is actually a tab(\t)
}
```

When I stringify this object with `JSON.stringify(o)`, it returns `"{"comments":"\t notes"}"`

If I parse that string back, it is giving back the original object, i.e `{"comments": "    notes"}`

But as per our requirement, we need to upper case the `JSON.stringify()` result. If we do `JSON.stringify(o).toUpperCase()`, it gives us `"{"COMMENTS":"\T NOTES"}"`

Is there any way to retain `"\t"` or the spaces in the stringified result ?

Comment: That's a weird requirement. Are you certain it's necessary?

Comment: What exactly is your requirement that would have you call `toUpperCase()` on a JSON string? Why not call it on the individual values (and possibly property names) before stringifying the object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try using the for in loop to iterate it over the keys as follows

```
var b={};
for(let item in o){
  b[item.toUpperCase()]=o[item].toUpperCase();
  console.log(b);
}
```

If you want to convert the nested object as well then use the following function and it will work fine.

```
function changeToUpperCase(obj) {
  var newobj = {};
  for (let item in obj) {
    if (typeof obj[item] == 'object') {
        newobj[item.toUpperCase()] = changeToUpperCase(obj[item]);
    } else {
        newobj[item.toUpperCase()] = obj[item].toUpperCase();
    }
  }
  return newobj
}
```

Comment: You'll want to initialise `b={}` outside of the loop though

Comment: @Vivek can you update your code to support nested structure ?

Answer (score 2):

If you not use double slash '\\' in your strings then you can try

```
replace('\\T','\t')
```

```js
var o = {
  "comments": " notes" // it first 4 spaces is actually a tab(\t)
}

let j = JSON.stringify(o).toUpperCase().replace('\\T','\t');

console.log(j);
```

Answer (score -2):

For more information [JSON.stringfy doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_replacer_parameter)

```
var input= {
   "comment": "    notes"
};

var result = JSON.stringfy(input, function(kay,value){
  if(value === "string"){
     return value.toUpperCase().trim();
  }
 });
console.log("RESULT ",result);
```